# SQL: how to check if at least one keyword from a keyword list exists in a string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following schema,

```
id   data_string
1    I have a pen.
2    Monday is not good.
3    I love Friday.
...  ...
```

And I also have a list of keywords `['pen', 'love', 'apple']`.

I want to write a SQL script to find **if any of the keyword in my list of keywords can be found in the data_string column of the table.**

And I'd like the output of the script be like

```
id   keyword_exist
1    true 
2    false
3    true
...  ...
```

Is this doable with SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
with keywords as (
  select ['pen', 'love', 'apple'] list
)
select t.*, regexp_contains(data_string, r'' || pattern) keyword_exist
from your_table t, 
( select array_to_string(list, '|') pattern
  from keywords
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```sql
SELECT ID, data_string,
    CASE WHEN data_string LIKE '% pen %' 
    OR data_string LIKE '% love %' 
    OR data_string LIKE '% apple %' THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False' 
    END AS keyword_exist
FROM table_name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).